# Como puedo simplificar mi codigo

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

La cosa es que estoy creando una ventana.
este es el codigo de uno de los botones:

```py
self.btn51 = tkinter.Button(master, text="0", command = self.printBut0)
self.btn51.place(x=180, y=380, width=120, height=40)
self.btn51.configure(font=("Caviar_Dreams", "15"))
```

Lo que hacen es: cuando presiono el boton imprime en un Entry el digito "0".
Y esta es la funcion que es llama por el boton:

```py
def printBut0(self):
    self.txtCalc.insert(len(self.txtCalc.get()),"0")
```

la cosa es que la funcion la repito muchas veces porque hay varios botones con esa funcion, pero imprimen distintos digitos, puedo de alguna manera hacer una para todos los botones?

Y agradezco si pueden decirme algo que pueda mejorar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar duplicar código tenés que identificar que es lo que cambia.
En este caso para crear un boton varia el `text`, `x` e `y`.
Entonces ponemos esos datos en una lista de diccionarios:

```
info_btns = [{"text": "0", "x": 180, "y": 380},
             # ...
             {"text": "9", "x": 540, "y": 500}}
```

Como `printBut0` depende del `text` del botón, lo adaptamos para que lo
reciba como argumento por *keyword*:

```
def printBut(self, text=""):
    self.txtCalc.insert(len(self.txtCalc.get()), text)
```

Luego, podes usar un *for loop* para iterar la lista y crear los botones:

```
for info_btn in info_btns:
    btn = tkinter.Button(master, text=info_btn["text"],
                         command=functools.partial(self.printBut,
                                                   text=info_btn["text"]))

    btn.place(x=info_btn["x"], y=info_btn["y"], width=120, height=40)
    btn.configure(font=("Caviar_Dreams", "15"))
```

Usamos la función `partial` del módulo `functools` para que el método
`printBut` reciba el `text` del botón correspondiente. Lo que hace es
devolver el mismo método pero con un argumento ya aplicado.
Un ejemplo de su uso:

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import repeat

def saludar(nombre, veces=1):
    for _ in repeat(None, veces):
        print(f"Hola {nombre}")

saludar_tres_veces = partial(saludar, veces=3)

saludar_tres_veces("mundo")
```